# Is there a way to have a "viewWillAppear" fuction that inizalises a class in swiftUI and prevents refrences until inialized?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webkit

I am looking for a way to initialize a class before my View loads in SwiftUI.  This class takes two args which are the `self` of the initializer and an `Int` value.  Then when initialized I want to call a get method inside of the Class and get an array of facebook videos (loaded in WebKit) to display.  Where the problem I have comes in is if I fetch the get method too soon it crashes, and then it will not let me create a var/let with the type of self of my View calling it.  To me, it seems like I need some sort of completion handler but I do not know to do that for this case.

Here is a portion of my `fetchDataBook` class that is being initialized to get information from a Facebook page I have permission to, and what needs to be initialized before the View loads the values of `getWebView()`.

```
    private let upperBoundRange: Int

    private var requests = [URLRequest]()
    private var WebViews = [WebView2]()

    init(upperBoundRange: Int) {
        self.upperBoundRange = upperBoundRange

        getToken()
    }

    //
    //
    // Create some sort of completsion handler to tell when it is safe to fetch webviews
    //
    //

    func getwebView(index: Int) -> WebView2 {
        print("Get views", WebViews[index])
        return WebViews[index]
    }

    private func setWebViews() {
        for i in 0...upperBoundRange {
            WebViews.append(WebView2(parent: parent, request: requests[i]))
        }
    }

    private func setLinks(data: NSArray) {
     // Code Not Shown to get links for setWebViews()
    }

    // Fetches FaceBook URL for Livestream
    private func getJSON(token: String) {
     // code not shown
    }

    private func getToken() {
      // code now shown
    }
```

Here is the basic struture of my SwiftUI View:

```
struct LiveMaster : View {
let fb = fetchDataBook(upperBoundRange 4)

ScrollView{
    VStack {
     self.fb.getwebView(index: 0)
     // Each displays WebSite from fetch in fetchDataBook class but cannot display them until the var in fetchDataBook has the values
    }

   VStack {

    }

    VStack {

    }

    VStack {

    }
}
```

Thank you and if you need more information I would be glad to edit this to clarify.  This has been a problem for the past couple of days that I cannot find a solution to, nor an easy way to ask.  Thank you.

Comment: you can use onAppear() in swiftUI which is the equivilent to viewWillAppear(), which should let you do what you need. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear

Comment: Thank you, I miss understood how that function worked.  I thought it was called once the View Appeared not would load.  That, however, does not solve my issue because the references to getwebView() in my VStacks still crashes the application because they are trying to get the WebView2 array before it has been set.

Comment: Your model should `@Publish` an optional. That way your view can be coded to handle the case where the data is `nil` and it will automatically be refreshed once the data is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is as Paulw11 said ***Your model should @Publish an optional.***  This worked perfectly, as soon as I added a Bool value that would change once the values have been set since it was not properly updated with my Array of WebView2's.  Then I just use @ObservedObject on my instances of that class and it worked perfectly with the if checks of that Bool value.  Thank you @Paulw11 for the suggestion.